# Using .htaccess to block referrer spam

Tags: security, .htaccess

Our forum gets targeted a lot by automated bots that try to register automatically.

We can see an example here from the error log

> [Sun Apr 03 14:04:46 2011] [error]
>   [client 70.183.110.133] File does not
>   exist:
>   /home/spoilert/public_html/forum/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Result:+captcha+decoded+(23+attempts);+registered+(registering+only+mode+is+ON);,
>   referer:
>   http://forum.spoilertv.co.uk/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Result:+captcha+decoded+%2823+attempts%29;+registered+%28registering+only+mode+is+ON%29;
>   [Sun Apr 03 13:45:54 2011] [error]
>   [client 70.183.110.133] File does not
>   exist:
>   /home/spoilert/public_html/2008,
>   referer:

I've updated my htaccess with this code

> SetEnvIfNoCase Referer
>   "^http://(W)decoded.*$" banned
>   Deny
>   from env=banned

It "should" deny any referrer link with the word decoded in it but it seems that it's not working. I still seem to be getting a few of these robots getting through with the same URL so it seems that it's still happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you change it to

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer ".*+decoded+.*" banned
Deny from env=banned
```

Comment: Thanks Bugfinder, I'll give it a go. I've never been very good a regex stuff, it gives me headaches :)

Comment: Really complex regex is a dark art, simple stuff is plausible, in short, the .* looks for the shortest match, so in a way, all that code does is say is there a "+decoded+" with some stuff before/after it in the string. I still stuff up sometimes, when Im trying to work it with groups and so on, but thats usually because I fail to count something correctly

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation, that's very helpful and useful to know in future